# Textual Dictionary Program

Tags: java, beginner, hash-map

I am a beginner in programming and I have written a little program that manages a list of words or strings to examine my understanding of Java and object oriented programming. I am interested in your thoughts!

#### Dictionary.java

This class contains the words and the methods for manipulating the word list.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Dictionary
{
    private String[] words;
    private File file;

    public Dictionary()
    {
        words = new String[1000];
        file = new File("words.txt");

        int i = 0;
        if (file.exists())
        {
            try
            {
                FileReader file_reader = new FileReader("words.txt");
                BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(file_reader);

                String word;
                while((word = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    words[i] = word;
                    i++;
                }

                buffered_reader.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                file.createNewFile();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        for(;i < 1000; i++)
            words[i] = "";
    }

    public void show_words(String filter)
    {
        if (filter.equals("*"))
        {
            for(String word : words)
            {
                if(word.equals(""))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else if(!(word.equals("<[d]>")))
                {
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(String word : words)
            {
                if(word.toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase()))
                {
                    System.out.println(word);
                }
                else if(word.equals(""))
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void add_word(String word)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i].equals("") || word.equals("<[d]>"))
            {
                words[i] = word;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void del_words(String string)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
            if (words[i].contains(string))
            {
                System.out.println("\"" + words[i] + "\" deleted");
                words[i] = "<[d]>";
            }
        }      
    }

    public void save_words()
    {
        try
        {
            FileWriter file_writer = new FileWriter("words.txt");
            BufferedWriter buffered_writer = new BufferedWriter(file_writer);
            int i = 0;
            while(words[i] != "")
            {
                if(!(words[i].equals("<[d]>")))
                {
                    buffered_writer.write(words[i]);
                    buffered_writer.newLine();
                }
                i++;
            }
            buffered_writer.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

#### Commander.java

This class takes the commands from the user and gives them to the dictionary methods or does other stuff with it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Commander
{
    private Dictionary dictionary;
    private Scanner input;

    public Commander()
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in);
        dictionary = new Dictionary();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("> ");
            String command = input.nextLine();

            if(command.equals("help"))
            {
                help();
            }
            else if(command.length() >= 4 && command.substring(0, 4).equals("show"))
            {
                dictionary.show_words(parse(command));
            }
            else if(command.length() >= 3 && command.substring(0, 3).equals("add"))
            {
                dictionary.add_word(parse(command));
            }
            else if(command.length() >= 3 && command.substring(0, 3).equals("del"))
            {
                dictionary.del_words(parse(command));
            }
            else if(command.equals("save"))
            {
                dictionary.save_words();
            }

            else if(command.equals("exit"))
            {
                dictionary.save_words();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("invalid syntax");
            }
        }
    }

    private String parse(String input)
    {
        String parsed = input.substring(input.indexOf(' ') + 1, input.length());
        return parsed;
    }

    private void help()
    {

        System.out.println("help - no arguments    - shows information");
        System.out.println("save - no arguments    - writing changes on hard drive");
        System.out.println("show - <string> or <*> - shows words");
        System.out.println("add  - <string>        - adds word to dictionary");
        System.out.println("del  - <string>        - deletes entrys that contain string");
    }
}
```

#### Start.java

```
public class Start
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Commander commander = new Commander();
        commander.init();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Limit scope

> ```
>     private File file;
> ```

This doesn't need to be an object field.  You only use it in the constructor, so it could just be a local variable.

#### Choose the right data type

> ```
>     private String[] words;
> ```

and later

> ```
>         words = new String[1000];
> ```

These could just be

```
    private List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you could get change

> ```
>                     words[i] = word;
>                     i++;
> ```

to just

```
                    words.add(word);
```

Get rid of

> ```
>         for(;i < 1000; i++)
>             words[i] = "";
> ```

And get rid of the various places you say things like

> ```
>                 else if(word.equals(""))
>                 {
>                     break;
>                 }
> ```

The list will only be as long as needed, so it doesn't have to handle dummy values.

> ```
>             if (words[i].contains(string))
>             {
>                 System.out.println("\"" + words[i] + "\" deleted");
>                 words[i] = "<[d]>";
>             }
> ```

could be

```
            while (i < words.size() && words.get(i).contains(string))
            {
                System.out.println("\"" + words.remove(i) + "\" deleted");
            }
```

Now we don't have fake values hiding in the dictionary.  So we don't need code like

> ```
>                 if(word.equals(""))
>                 {
>                     break;
>                 }
>                 else if(!(word.equals("<[d]>")))
>                 {
>                     System.out.println(word);
>                 }
> ```

We can just say

```
                System.out.println(word);
```

And

> ```
>         for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
>         {
>             if (words[i].equals("") || word.equals("<[d]>"))
>             {
>                 words[i] = word;
>                 break;
>             }
>         }
> ```

could just be

```
        words.add(word);
```

No need to find a blank spot.

#### `try`-with-resources

> ```
>             try
>             {
>                 FileReader file_reader = new FileReader("words.txt");
>                 BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(file_reader);
>
>                 String word;
>                 while((word = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null)
>                 {
>                     words[i] = word;
>                     i++;
>                 }
>
>                 buffered_reader.close();
>             }
> ```

If there is an exception, this never closes the `buffered_reader`.

```
            try (BufferedReader buffered_reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words.txt")))
            {
                String word;
                while ((word = buffered_reader.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    words.add(word);
                }
            }
```

With the `try`-with-resources form, the `buffered_reader` will automatically be closed.

#### Command processing

> ```
>         while (true)
>         {
>             System.out.print("> ");
>             String command = input.nextLine();
>
>             if(command.equals("help"))
>             {
>                 help();
>             }
>             else if(command.length() >= 4 && command.substring(0, 4).equals("show"))
>             {
>                 dictionary.show_words(parse(command));
>             }
>             else if(command.length() >= 3 && command.substring(0, 3).equals("add"))
>             {
>                 dictionary.add_word(parse(command));
>             }
>             else if(command.length() >= 3 && command.substring(0, 3).equals("del"))
>             {
>                 dictionary.del_words(parse(command));
>             }
>             else if(command.equals("save"))
>             {
>                 dictionary.save_words();
>             }
>
>             else if(command.equals("exit"))
>             {
>                 dictionary.save_words();
>                 break;
>             }
>             else
>             {
>                 System.out.println("invalid syntax");
>             }
>         }
> ```

This could be a `switch`

```
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("> ");
            String[] command_pieces = input.nextLine().split("\\s+", 2);

            switch (command_pieces[0]) {
            case "help":
                help();
                break;
            case "show":
                dictionary.show_words(command_pieces[1]);
                break;
            case "add":
                dictionary.add_word(command_pieces[1]);
                break;
            case "del":
                dictionary.del_words(command_pieces[1]);
                break;
            case "save":
                dictionary.save_words();
                break;
            case "exit":
                dictionary.save_words();
                return;
            default:
                System.out.println("invalid syntax");
            }
        }
```

This saves some typing, as using `split` with `nextLine` means that you don't have to take the `substring` or check that the string is long enough.

#### Help

You should include `exit` in your `help` instructions.  So people know it's `exit` and not `quit` or `stop` or something else.  You could also explain that `exit` includes a save operation.  So people don't think they have to type `save` every time.

#### Advanced

You could pick a type that better optimizes substring searches, like a modified Trie or a full text index.  Even something like a `HashSet` would help with full string matches.

Comment: Thank you very much for your work! This will help me a lot for improving my programming skills!